# Cron trigger in Quartz.Net for hourly values

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I was checking out cron triggers for Quartz.Net and noticed that when I use any other trigger apart from hourly, it offsets the Time to UTC(which should always be the case), but when I do the same for an Hourly cron, it picks the local time.

For example

Suppose my Start Time is `2014-05-31 15:44:00`

For **Hourly Schedule** for the next 6 occasions

> Cron Expression: `0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *`

is given as

```
5/31/2014 5:30:00 PM +00:00
5/31/2014 6:30:00 PM +00:00
5/31/2014 7:30:00 PM +00:00
5/31/2014 8:30:00 PM +00:00
5/31/2014 9:30:00 PM +00:00
5/31/2014 10:30:00 PM +00:00
```

This shows the time in localtime.

But when I try say a **weekly schedule**

> Cron: `0 44 15 ? * SUN,MON *`

The schedule comes up as

```
6/1/2014 10:14:00 AM +00:00
6/2/2014 10:14:00 AM +00:00
6/8/2014 10:14:00 AM +00:00
6/9/2014 10:14:00 AM +00:00
6/15/2014 10:14:00 AM +00:00
6/16/2014 10:14:00 AM +00:00
```

Which is offset to UTC, which is right.

This is the code which I am using

```
var cron = new Quartz.CronExpression("0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *");
DateTimeOffset? nextFire = cron.GetNextValidTimeAfter(Convert.ToDateTime("5/31/2014 4:30:00 PM"));
```

Obviously, I change the parameters dynamically.

This is the piece of code which does the schedule calculation

```
  var jobItem = (DbContext.jobs.Where(job => job.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();

                List<DateTimeOffset> scheduleTimes = new List<DateTimeOffset>();

                var time = DateTimeOffset.Now;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobItem.CronExpression))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                    {
                        var date = GetScheduleForCron(jobItem.CronExpression, time);
                        scheduleTimes.Add(date.Value);
                        time = date.Value;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    var jobAttribute =
                           (from attribute in DbContext.jobattributes
                            where attribute.JobId == jobItem.Id
                            select attribute.SpecificDate).FirstOrDefault();

                    scheduleTimes.Add(jobAttribute.Value);

                }


    public static DateTimeOffset? GetScheduleForCron(string cronexpression, DateTimeOffset date)
    {
        var cron = new CronExpression(cronexpression);
        return cron.GetNextValidTimeAfter(date.DateTime);
    }
```

EDIT: I used http://www.cronmaker.com/ to cross verify my schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confusing the usage of local and UTC times. Especially if you have `Convert.ToDateTime("5/31/2014 4:30:00 PM")`, `DateTimeOffset.Now` or `date.DateTime` . The General rule with Quartz is that

> UTC times go in, UTC times come out

. Here's sample that runs your case with expected output (used the non-builder API for brevity):

```
var firstTrigger = new CronTriggerImpl();
firstTrigger.CronExpressionString = "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *";
firstTrigger.StartTimeUtc = new DateTime(2014, 05, 31, 15, 44, 00).ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine("first trigger fire times:");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(firstTrigger, null, 6).Select(x => x.ToLocalTime())));

var secondTrigger = new CronTriggerImpl();
secondTrigger.CronExpressionString = "0 44 15 ? * SUN,MON *";
secondTrigger.StartTimeUtc = new DateTime(2014, 05, 31, 15, 44, 00).ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine("second trigger fire times:");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(secondTrigger, null, 6).Select(x => x.ToLocalTime())));
```

It will output (in my GMT+3 locale, cron trigger runs on current locale's time zone by default):

```
first trigger fire times
 31.5.2014 16:00:00 +03:00
 31.5.2014 17:00:00 +03:00
 31.5.2014 18:00:00 +03:00
 31.5.2014 19:00:00 +03:00
 31.5.2014 20:00:00 +03:00
 31.5.2014 21:00:00 +03:00
second trigger fire times:
 1.6.2014 15:44:00 +03:00
 2.6.2014 15:44:00 +03:00
 8.6.2014 15:44:00 +03:00
 9.6.2014 15:44:00 +03:00
 15.6.2014 15:44:00 +03:00
 16.6.2014 15:44:00 +03:00
```

Comment: Thanks Marko!

Also if I use your code, we need to include Common.Logging as reference, else we get type initialization exception.

Comment: No problem. Yes, always include Common.Logging in project as that's the abstraction that Quartz.NET requires.